# How to create bucket in Couchbase using kubectl with curl command and insert data into it.?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, couchbase, kubectl

I have tried creating an bucket in Couchbase using the following commands, Its showing some 202 Accepted response and it is in progress status. But it is not completed. I have waiting for a while and listed created bucket I wont found any newly created bucket.

Commands-
curl -v -X POST http://localhost:8091/pools/default/buckets 
-u Administrator:password 
-d name=testBucket 
-d ramQuotaMB=100

[image]

I have also tried to create an bucket in couchbase cli using kubectl using the following command, Here also initially shows newly bucket but when creation is not completed. It again doesnt show.

Command-

couchbase-cli bucket-create -c localhost:8091 --username Administrator 
--password password --bucket TestBucket --bucket-type couchbase 
--bucket-ramsize 100

Comment: Are you using the Couchbase Kubernetes operator? https://www.couchbase.com/products/cloud/kubernetes - if you are, then it's possible that the operator is removing new buckets automatically. Update the YAML to add a bucket instead.

Comment: When you say "I have waiting for a while and listed created bucket I wont found any newly created bucket." how are you checking to see if the bucket has been created?

Comment: I have followed this link to setup Couchbase using kubectl using AWS..
https://github.com/couchbase-partners/amazon-eks-couchbase

Comment: Matthew Groves 
I am following some commands-

-  kubectl exec -it cb-example-0000 bash
-  cd /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs/

Thereafter creating command and GET command .. When I do hit the GET API for certain amount of time I can able to see newly created bucket and again the newly bucket disappeared.

Comment: @MatthewGroves 

Which YAML file needs to updated. And which parameter as well??

Comment: @MatthewGroves 
Now here the default bucket is created. I am not able to generate new document in the default bucket as well or add data into the bucket.. If you have any idea on this it would be great. I want to use the curl command to update or add the data or document in the bucket.

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look at the documentation, since that GitHub repo hasn't been updated and there have been several releases since then: https://docs.couchbase.com/operator/current/overview.html

Comment: @MatthewGroves  I have gone through the above nothing helped me to sort out my issue.. I am still getting the same error..